# recursive function not working for CheckLink function

Tags: java, recursion

I have below code but when i try to run the check function its giving me stackOverFlow error please help

when i debugged it its going till "return true;", but also entering else.

**NOTE :
I have this data in my collection :
{1=[2, 3], 2=[3], 3=[4], 4=[3], 5=[6], 6=[5]}**

How can i find the link between two nodes

```
private Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> graphList = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();


private boolean checkLink(ArrayList<Integer> dataListFirst, int match) {
        if (dataListFirst != null) {
            for (int data : dataListFirst) {
                if (data == match) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    checkLink(graphList.get(data), match);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What if your graph has a cycle? That would explain the never ending recursion and StackOverlowErr.

Comment: Then how i can i check the link between the given  (1,3)

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the retun value of your recursive call:

```
if (data == match) {
    return true;
} else {
    checkLink(graphList.get(data), match); // <--- Return value unused
}
```

You can modify your code to check if the recursive calls find your element:

```
private boolean checkLink(ArrayList<Integer> dataListFirst, int match) {
    if (dataListFirst != null) {
        for (int data : dataListFirst) {
            if (data == match || checkLink(graphList.get(data), match)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

This code still could has a problem if your graph has cycles, you could return false in your function when you are trying to check the same value again.

```
// Just call the recursive function with an empty list of elements
private boolean checkLink(ArrayList<Integer> dataListFirst, int match) {
    return checkLink(dataListFirst, match, new ArrayList<Integer>());
}


private boolean checkLink(ArrayList<Integer> dataListFirst, int match, List<Integer> nodes) {
    if (dataListFirst != null) {
        for (int data : dataListFirst) {
            if (nodes.contains(data)) {
                return false;
            }
            nodes.add(data);
            if (data == match || checkLink(graphList.get(data), match, nodes)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It gives false when i check link  between 4,1 for the this data   {1=[2, 3], 2=[3], 3=[4], 4=[3], 5=[6], 6=[5]}

Comment: This seems to be correct. 4=[3] and 3=[4].  4 is not linked with 1

Comment: 1->3->4 it has  a path :( if its 1,6 only in such cases  it must return false

Comment: Your original code only check one way, in this case it checks if there is a path from 4 to 1. If you also want to check if there is a path from 1 to 4, you need to make two calls to this method or modify it a little bit to check both ways.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you only want to make a recursive call after checking all the elements of the current `ArrayList`. And you should use the value returned by the recursive call (that's the reason your recursion didn't end after `return true;`) :

```
private boolean checkLink(ArrayList<Integer> dataListFirst, int match) 
{
    if (dataListFirst != null) {
        for (int data : dataListFirst) {
            if (data == match) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (int data : dataListFirst) {
            boolean found = checkLink(graphList.get(data), match);
            if (found)
                return found;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm not sure this will work in all cases, though, since if there are cycles in the graph you may get into an infinite recursion without ever finding the desired node.